# Scrollorama - Horizontal scrolling does not work

Tags: jquery

I have been messing with scrollorama - the plugin for jquery and I am trying to make it work horizontally.

www.nmyster.co.uk/testGround

The site above have my testing and for some reason when I scroll to the right, one of elements does not fade in..
Why is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit jquery.scrollorama.js

**string 102:**
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
**change to:**
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollLeft(),